# Status of falsafa in sunni islam?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, kufr

I often come across mentions of Al-Kindi, Al-Farabi, Ibn Sina (Avicenna), and Ibn Rushd (Averroes). At least with regard to Ibn Sina, I'm certain I have seen numerous fatawa by authoritative sunni scholars that they consider him a kafir (for example, al-Ghazali reports that Ibn Sina claimed to be allowed to drink alcohol regularly for its medical benefits without medical indication that he needs to drink it; I'm not sure al-Ghazali declared Ibn Sina a kafir, though).

What is the status of the other three in this regard?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a bad question, could the downvoter let me know?

Comment: I'm quite sure that most of those fatawa have been spoken out by scholars who have been asked for such fatwas by higher authorities, so those where mostly "ordered fatwas". Al-Ghazali and ibn Taymiyyah have both dealt with falsafa and declared it as haram for people with no strong faith etc.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I'm not sure what to do with that. Do we ignore those fatawa then? If a scholar condemns someone as a kafir whom he doesn't consider to be one, what does that make the scholar if not a kafir?

Comment: I've on the other site read fatwas declaring Goethe a muslim based on very few evidences. I don't give much on such fatwas

Comment: @Medi1Saif I haven't read fatawa to that effect, but I have come across that sentiment. Never by any reputable scholar, and giving someone the benefit of the doubt for being muslim - not that there is much doubt in Goethe's case - seems like a different matter from pronouncing a muslim to be kafir, and certainly if the one making the pronouncement is al-Ghazali or ibn Taymiyyah as opposed to Abdullah from the local mosque, if you forgive the flippancy.

Comment: I know that ibn Rushd has been declared a zindeeq and banned for a period of time and his books have been burnt. And maybe you can add other names to your list like ibn Rushd's "teacher" ibn Tufail. But the point is that there's no real consensus among sunni scholars about falsafa being haram. And I know of philosophers who say that al-Ghazali is the real and only Muslim philosopher while the others only made some additions or explanations of works of Greek philosophers he created an Philosophy based on Islam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to point at a very important matter even if many sunni Muslims have this idea of philosophy being haram there are many quotes of ibn Taymiyyah and al-Ghazali (the most quoted scholars when it comes to declare falsafa as haram) which show that this ruling isn't a general rule, but only applies to some disciplines of philosophy.

About **ibn Rushd** the grandson i found [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/130484) which shows that some of his taughts have been rejected, and that he was banned and his books have been burnt and some say arrested maybe he was banned and later arrested in his house in Marrakech (what I've been thought was that he was banned to a village in al-Anadalus where only Jews lived). Here some quotes from the fatwa:

> Shaykh ash-Shuyookh Ibn Hamawiyyah said: 
> When I entered the city, I asked about Ibn Rushd and I was told that he was under house arrest on the orders of the caliph Ya‘qoob, and no one was allowed to visit him, because of the many strange views that were narrated from him, and the many shunned branches of knowledge that were attributed to him. He died under house arrest in Marrakesh.

You can see his biography in Siyar A‘laam an-Nubala’ (21/307-310)

> Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah (may Allah have mercy on him) said:
>
> When Ibn Sina (Avicenna) and his ilk realised that the words of the Messenger cannot be interpreted in this philosophical manner – rather they became certain that the meaning that he intended was what the people understood – they tried to explain that by saying: He was addressing the masses in a manner that they could understand, even though he knew that the truth with regard to that particular issue was not as the people understood it. Hence what these people were effectively saying was that the Messengers lied in order to serve a purpose. This is the way of Ibn Rushd (Averroes) and others who follow esoteric interpretations (baatiniyyah). End quote.
>
> Majmoo‘ al-Fataawa (19/157)

[This post](http://www.muslm.org/vb/showthread.php?341132-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%B9%D8%B8%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%81%D8%A9-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%AF%D8%A9-%D8%A5%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%B3%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B2%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%8A-%D9%88%D8%A3%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B9%D9%87%D9%85) quotes both **al-Farabi** and **ibn Sina** in one sentence from al-Munqid min ad-dalal of al-Ghazali saying they are kufar

> قال الإمام الغزالي في كتابه "المنقذ من الضلال" : لا شك في كفرهما أي الفارابي وابن سينا
>
> Al Ghazali said in his al-Munqid min ad-dalal: there's no doubt about them being apostates, he meant al-Frabi and ibn Sina

and a quote of ibn Taymiyyah saying that *ibn Rushd* is among those philosophers the closest to Islam.

> وقد ذكر شيخ الإسلام ابن تيمية أن ابن رشد الحفيد خالف قدماء الفلاسفة في بعض مذاهبهم وأنه أقلهم كفراً وأقربهم إلى الإسلام انظر مجموع الفتاوى [17/289،295،357].
>
> And Shaykh al-Islam ibn Taymiyyah said that ibn Rushd the grandson has opposed the ancient philosophers in some of their thoughts and that he is the lowest among them in apostasy and closest to Islam, See Majmo'o al-Fatwa 17/289,295,357

And here's a quote from an other [fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/62822) quoting siyar a'laam an-Nubala' of ad-Dahabi about al-Kindi (see also on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Kindi#Critics_and_patrons)):

> كان يقال له فيلسوف العرب، وكان متهماً في دينه بخيلاً ساقط المروءة
>
> He was called the philosopher of the Arabs, and he was accused in his faith, grasping and had no sense of honor.

Comment: Could you translate the Arabic parts? I can't read Arabic.

Comment: Thank you; this sounds like ibn Taymiyyah did consider ibn Rushd a kafir, but just barely?